# Missing installer cache - SharePoint 2013 - reasons for missing and how to protect it?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, installation

We have observed that installer cache is missing in our SharePoint. We used OPUTIL to copy the files from healthy servers in the farm but didnt help. We had to rebuild the whole farm again to proceed with the patch upgrade but just after one week we again see the missing files in installer cache(not all by a few day by day). We dont clean our servers with any cleaning tools. What could be the possible reasons for this and how to avoid in future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issues multi times and couple of time we have to rebuild faulty server. In our case there are multiple reasons for this

- Due to space issue windows admin delete the files from installer folder.as he think does not required in future and deleted old files.
- One time culprit was Antivirus, which think these files are threat and av deleted these. As per AV settings. We avoid this by excluding this folder from av scan.
- One time we had issue with another audit tool which delete the files from c drive due to heavy movement. Again we disabled that tool.

So you have to check what software installed on ur server and what they doing with this folder.

Comment: Windows team will not delete those files, Antivirus exclusions are already taken care.
Audit Tool - Heavy movement? What are those tools in specific? 
My SharePoint farm is heavily customized, involves complex Nintex workflows, and heavy custom coding. Threshold settings are as high as 5Lak, Will these have any impact for the loss of those files considering the heavy load the servers?